# Get value for each day in month

Tags: mysql

I have a table :

```
+--------------+
| stat         |
+--------------+
| date         |
| onlineUsers  |
| messagesSent |
+--------------+
```

I gather statistics every 10 minutes and save them to db. How can I get `date, max(OnlineUsers), sum(messagesSent)` for each day in period of time with single sql query?

Comment: This is a pretty basic aggregation query.  If you are using SQL, you should know the basics and `group by` is a basic.

Comment: Easiest way, I think, is creating some function to generate query with `SELECT * WHERE DATE(\`date\`) = DATE(\`every_day_in_period\`)`. But I understand that it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as :

```
SELECT date, MAX(OnlineUsers), SUM(messagesSent)
FROM stat
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31'
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: In this case it'll return all rows from table for this period I think, but I need only 30 with summed information for day. Column Date has datetime datatype and keeps not only date but time also.

Comment: ok, expanding your idea with DATE(`date`) i get my information

Answer (score 0):

General problem in this situation is that not all the time periods have any data. Hence you get a gap. For example if you wanted to know the number of people who logged on to a system each day of the month you could do:-

```
SELECT logon_date, COUNT(*)
FROM logon_table
GROUP BY logon_date
```

If nobody had logged on one day then that date would be missing while you probably want that date with a count of 0. This problem becomes really obvious when you try a draw a graph with the results.

Solution is to generate a range of all the basic unit and then join that against the actual data.

For example:-

```
SELECT aDate, MAX(OnlineUsers), SUM(messagesSent)
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-05-01', INTERVAL units.i + 10 * tens.i DAY) AS aDate
    FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN stat
ON sta.`date` = sub1.aDate
WHERE aDate BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31'
GROUP BY aDate
```

This is using a couple of sub queries to generate all the numbers from 0 to 99 and adding that to the start date (you could add a smaller number, this is just for convenience). The real data is then left joined to this list of dates, and from the results of that you can use the aggregate functions to get the details you want.

You can easily expand this idea for different time period (eg, the hours of the day, etc).